# Install updates on shutdown (on notebook)

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, updates

On all my computers I changed windows update to download updates, but not install them automatically (because I hate being interrupted by some installation routine). Instead I install the updates on computer shutdown, which works very well for me.

When new updates are available, my two desktop computers change the shutdown button in the start menu to "install updates & shutdown", which I use.

For some strange reason this does not happen on my notebook (well, or it does happen on some rare occasions, sometimes when I attached my notebook to AC power supply?).

I want to install the updates on shutdown on my notebook even when I'm on battery power, but I can find no option to enable (or disable) this.

How do I get the shutdown option to change to "install updates and shutdown"? (Or, how might I have disabled this - I don't think I did, but who knows).

The systems are all running Windows 7.

Comment: The AC only behavior is not unique to Windows. On MacOS and Linux, the update manager will also prompt you to ask if you want to update without plugging it into A/C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep it's a feature, your notebook losing power during an update could be bad news so the best way to avoid that is only let you install updates when the machine is on AC power.

Comment: I guessed that, but how Do I disable this feature?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.